# Solving tower of Hanoi with given arrangements

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

I am given an arrangement of valid tower of Hanoi disks. The arrangement is given as an array.

For example [2,2,0]: the indices of the array are the identifiers of the disks, ordered from small to large, and the values of the array are the positions of the corresponding disks (positions are always 0, 1 or 2). In the case of [2,2,0], the smallest two disks are at the third pole, while the largest disk is at the first pole:

```
      |           |           |
      |           |          [0]
   [22222]        |         [111] 
  ----+----   ----+----   ----+----
```

Another example: [0,2,1]

```
      |           |           |
      |           |           |
     [0]       [22222]      [111] 
  ----+----   ----+----   ----+----
```

Would it be possible to solve the problem recursively for the remaining steps required to move all disks to the target pole (second pole)?

```
public int solveForSteps(int[] disks){
    // Is there a possible way to solve with given arrangements?
}
```

Comment: Do have a look about for posting a question on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: Confusing. Try to state the problem with greater clarity.

Comment: Pole and peg mean the same thing. In towers of Hanoi, there are only three poles/pegs.  Discs are what gets moved.  With that in mind, would you please clarify your question and explain your array notation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have a recursive solution for you. When you look at the usual recursive algorithm for Tower of Hanoi, the actual states can occur deep within the recursion tree, and if you would imagine that such a state is passed to your function, then to further solve the problem from that state requires not only a recursive call, but also rebuilding the stack of "outer" recursive calls. This seems to make it quite complex.

But you can do it iteratively. Here is one way to do it:

```java
static void solveForSteps(int[] disks) {
    int n = disks.length;
    // Calculate the next target rod for each of the disks
    int target = 2; // The biggest disk should go to the rightmost rod
    int[] targets = new int[n];
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        targets[i] = target;
        if (disks[i] != target) {
            // To allow for this move, the smaller disk needs to get out of the way
            target = 3 - target - disks[i];
        }
    }
    int i = 0;
    while (i < n) { // Not yet solved?
        // Find the disk that should move
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (targets[i] != disks[i]) { // Found it
                target = targets[i]; // This and smaller disks should pile up here 
                System.out.format("move disk %d from rod %d to %d.\n", i, disks[i], target);
                disks[i] = target; // Make move
                // Update the next targets of the smaller disks
                for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                    targets[j] = target;
                    target = 3 - target - disks[j];
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will print the remaining moves that are necessary to move all disks to the rightmost pole. If instead you want to target the centre pole, then just change `int target = 2` to `int target = 1`.

Comment: hello, I'm currently trying to tackle the same issue here so, is it possible for you to provide a bit of explanation to newbies like me about the logic behind some areas of your code like these bits:                                                                                                 
 for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        targets[i] = target;
        if (disks[i] != target)                                                                                                               and this: target = 3 - target - disks[j];

Comment: it would be really helpful if u could maybe have some "//text" beside those bits so I can understand and adapt based on ur solution

Answer (score 1):

To solve the Towers of Hanoi from an arbitrary position, you can use a recursive procedure similar to the standard solution that works from the standard start position.

It just has to be a little more general.

Write a recursive procedure **moveDisks(maxSize,targetPeg)** that moves all the disks with size <= **maxSize** to the peg **targetPeg**, like this:

1. Find the largest disk **m** such that **m.size <= maxSize** and **m** is *not* on **targetPeg**.  If there is no such disk, then return, because all the disks with size <= **maxSize** are already in the right place.
2. Let **sourcePeg** be the peg where **m** is currently, and let **otherPeg** be the the peg that isn't **sourcePeg** or **targetPeg**.
3. Call **moveDisks(m.size-1, otherPeg)** recursively to get the smaller disks out of the way.
4. Move **m** from **sourcePeg** to **targetPeg**.
5. Call **moveDisks(m.size-1, targetPeg)** recursively to put the smaller disks where they belong.

In Java, I would write it like this:

```
/**
 * Solve towers of hanoi from an arbitrary position
 * 
 * @param diskPositions the current peg for each disk (0, 1, or 2) in increasing
 *                      order of size.  This will be modified
 * @param disksToMove  number of smallest disks to moves
 * @param targetPeg target peg for disks to move
 */
static void moveDisks(int[] diskPositions, int disksToMove, int targetPeg)
{
    for (int badDisk = disksToMove-1; badDisk >= 0; --badDisk) {
        int currentPeg = diskPositions[badDisk];
        if (currentPeg != targetPeg) {
            // found the largest disk on the wrong peg

            // sum of the peg numbers is 3, so to find the other one:
            int otherPeg = 3 - targetPeg - currentPeg;

            // before we can move badDisk, we have to get the smaller
            // ones out of the way
            moveDisks(diskPositions, badDisk, otherPeg);

            // Move
            diskPositions[badDisk] = targetPeg;
            System.out.println(
                "Move " + badDisk + " from " + currentPeg + " to " + targetPeg
            );

            //Now we can put the smaller ones in the right place
            moveDisks(diskPositions, badDisk, targetPeg);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

... well, I wouldn't write it *exactly* like this in real life.  You can actually remove the second recursive call and the break, because the remaining iterations in the loop will accomplish the same thing.

Comment: hello, I'm also currently learning about the same topic 2 years later right now and I was just wondering, if I wanted my function to return the "number" of steps as an int, can I set a variable size = 0 and keep on incrementing under every movedisk(0 method?

Comment: That would work, and it's a good way to start, but then you should figure out a way to optimize it to reduce complexity.  Counting to 2^N takes way too long.